# How can I show a tabbar when pushing a UIViewController onto the Navigation stack

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

So it is very easy to hide the tabbar when you push a view controller onto the navigation controller stack:

```
uiViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

works just peachy.

Put let's say I want to push deeper into the stack and show it again?

Setting

```
 laterUIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

on some later view controller doesn't make it reappear.  It's still hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You could try subclassing `UIViewController` and overriding the

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; }
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO; }
```

And then using that subclass as the superclass of the view controller that you want to show the bottom bar.

Comment: I got something like this to sort of work. The animation is wrong though when the view reappears.

The view will appear was not respected when going back so I had to jump through a bunch of hoops to make back work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES; }
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround: if you don't animate switching between view controllers it should work OK.

The idea is to make your tabbar controller's view size bigger so tabbar (which is at the bottom of the view) goes out of the screen and restore the view size when hiding the view.

In your view controller that should hide a tab bar define the following methods:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect r = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
    r.size.height +=self.tabBarController.tabbar.frame.size.height;
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = r;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); //for iPhone portrait
}
```

You need to make sure that in your app delegate tabbar controler and window outlets are defined and properly linked with XIB

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try un hidding it, so you tell it to hide, it hides, but then you tell it to not hide it (i dont know if it re shows it if you set this to no) but it looks like it isnt, either that or u are telling it to not hide when the view controller you want the bar in has been pushed already and it does not un hide the bar until the next view controller has been pushed, so you should try to set it as unhidden youself.